# How can I configure Centos 7 KVM network with CloudStack network in order to manage vlan and have 2 subnet inside cloudstack?

Tags: networking, centos, kvm-virtualization, cloudstack

I am new in kvm and Cloudstack and I have no idea how configure CloudStack in a single Host KVM having an internal network attached to VM's (IP: 192.168.1.x) and a second Network for "External" routing with managed also with CloudStack internal FW.

My idea is to have an infrastructure like this pic:

[image: kvm cloudstack]

When I install cloudstack I am only able to enable for all VM the "external network" having internal automatically managed by cloudstack with apipa.

any suggetion?

Other idea could also be enable NAT for all VM navigating trough external network using the Physical KVM external IP (10.0.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

From high level, you can use openvswitch and create 3 bridges:

1. br-mgmt -> it will act as mgmt interface for Hypervisor, linked with em4
2. br-int -> internal bridge, no physical interface.
3. br-ext -> external bridge, having 3 nics

now in cloudstack, create 3 physical networks while creating zone(advanced):

cloud-mgmt -> bridge would be br-mgmt

cloud-int -> bridge would be br-int

cloud-ext -> bridge would be br-ext

now create ip pool of 192.168.1.x in cloud-int and 10.0.1.x in cloud-ext with vlan 2050(ensure both are using dhcp)

on the mgmt switch port connecting to em4 set it as access vlan 2110 and other as trunk connecting em{1..3}

Answer (score -2):

You can see this blog as an example https://rohityadav.cloud/blog/cloudstack-kvm/

Comment: Please do nut just link to a site, please include the solution to OPs problem in your post and maybe include the link as a reference.